# Estou com problemas para fechar um form( no caso o main form) quando abro um segundo form

Tags: delphi

Eu ja tentei isso:

```
procedure TForm1.btnYesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form4:=TForm4.Create(Application);
Form4.ShowModal;
Form1.Hide;
end;
```

E isso tbm:

```
procedure TForm1.btnYesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form4:=TForm4.Create(Application);
Form4.ShowModal;
Form1.Close;
end;
```

Mas nada funciona, ja ate tentei usar um procedure.

Comment: Form1.Close; já fecha o form qual o problema mesmo, seja mias especifico.

Comment: o problema e q nao esta fechando do jeito que tinha, ele so cria o form 4 mas nao fecha o form1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Linha depois do ShowModal só é executada depois que você fecha o Form4, por isso não está executando o Hide ou o Close no Form1.

Substitua por

```
Form4.Show;
```

e teste novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Não faz muito sentido fechar o Main Form enquanto outro está aberto pois o fechamento do main encerra a aplicação. Então, se entendi corretamente, você quer que o main form fique invisível enquanto o outro é exibido. Esse código deve resolver:

`procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
    Visible := False;
    try
      form2.ShowModal;
    finally
      form1.Visible := True;
      form2.Free;
    end;
  end;`